# SQL Table handle large amounts of records

Tags: sql, large-data, records

I need to make sure that a table of mine can handle in excess of 1,000,000 records.

Can I have some advice on my table code to determine if it can indeed handle this amount of records.

Here is my code:

```
USE [db_person_cdtest]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [Person](
    [PersonID] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ID] [varchar](20),
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [AddressLine1] [varchar](50),
    [AddressLine2] [varchar](50),
    [AddressLine3] [varchar](50),
    [MobilePhone] [varchar](20),
    [HomePhone] [varchar](20),
    [Description] [varchar](10),
    [DateModified] [datetime],
    [PersonCategory] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Comment] [varchar](max),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PersonID] DESC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

Comment: Depends on your queries what indexes you need.

Answer (score 0):

Almost any table structure in almost any database can handle a million records.  That is not a large number of records for a modern computer running modern software.

Your structure looks reasonable.  One question is whether the fields are always large enough to hold the value in the data.  It looks like you are using SQL Server.  There is no difference in storage or performance to declaring a `varchar(50)` versus a `varchar(8000)`.  "50" seems on the low side to me.

Another comment is that you have a `DateModified` column.  I would suggest that you also keep a history table of the modifications.  It is often important to know what changed, when it changed, and what the values were before the change.

In more advanced systems, you would not be storing a person's address and telephone number in the same table as their unique ids.  A person could have more than one address (shipping address, billing address, home address, etc.).  A person could have many telephone numbers (landline number, mobile number, work number, work mobile, etc.).  And, you have no fields for email address, Facebook id, and so on.  Contact information is more complex than a few fields in a table.

Finally, as a matter of habit, I almost always include the following fields at the end of every table:

```
CreatedBy varchar(255) default system_user,
CreataedAt datetime not null default getdate()
```

This let's me know who and when a row was created.